# How to create a local LRS and intergrate with Tin can Api using PHP to run on my SCORM package

Tags: php, scorm, tin-can-api

I am trying to create a SCORM package and generate statements for the same.

I want to create a local LRS & Tin Can Api setup and generate statements from my scorm and display result in my php page.

I have created a LRS using the following link (http://onetarek.com/tin-can-api/guidephp-simple-lrs-with-tin-can-api/).

I have downloaded Tin Can Php sample and installed in my local, Unfortunatly it is not working. As i need to set my endpoint and auth credentials. I have no idea to do it to my local setup of LRS.

How to do this ?

I also want to host my SCORM package to any LMS and test with these setup.

I have analysed many forums and post, but nothing worked out.

I am lost. Need some resolution.

Kindly help.

-Vignesh Selvarajan

Answer (score 5):

That post is quite old and even the original author probably wouldn't suggest that approach. He would probably suggest, and if your LRS must be local and PHP I would agree, that you should check out the Learning Locker LRS.

http://learninglocker.net/

Alternatively you could use Rustici's SCORM Cloud which supports import/launch for both SCORM and Tin Can packages, and will create statements in the LRS for launched SCORM content. It has an API for integrating with an LMS. You may also want to check out the Dispatch feature for hosting packages in other LMSs.

http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/

HTH.